# Stack test fails on dependency

Tags: haskell, testing, build, haskell-stack

Say I have the following test package configured:

```
test-suite foo-test
  ghc-options:         -Wall -Werror
  cpp-options:         -DTEST
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      app, test
  build-depends:       Foo, base >= 4.8 && < 4.9, containers >= 0.5 && <0.6, split >= 0.2 && < 0.3, hspec, QuickCheck
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

And the following spec file:

```
  import Test.Hspec

  main :: IO ()
  main = hspec $ do
    describe "True" $ do
      it "True" $ do
        True `shouldBe` True
```

And a library definition like so:

```
library
  build-depends:       base, slack-api, text, lens, hashmap, exceptions, mtl, warp
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings
                     , TemplateHaskell
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  Exposed-modules:     Main
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

When I run `stack build`, the library builds correctly.
However, when I run `slack test`, this fails with:

```
slack-api-0.9: test (suite: tests)
Foo-0.1.0.0: test (suite: foo-test)
Completed 2 action(s).
Test suite failure for package slack-api-0.9
    tests:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
Full log available at /Users/abe/github/personal/foo/.stack-work/logs/slack-api-0.9-test.log
```

The listed log file is empty. There is an additional Foo-0.1.1.1.log file which contains

```
True
  True

Finished in 0.0011 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

So my "test" is running. But so is a test from the dependency (and failing). What could be causing this? And how do I prevent this?

Comment: Can you include your stack.yaml file contents?

Comment: Also, most likely explanation: you want to set `extra-dep: true` on the `slack-api` package in stack.yaml.